# How to print formatted string to the same line in stdout with Go?

Tags: string, macos, go, stdout

I am iterating over an array and printing a formatted string with each array element to the terminal (stdout). Rather than printing each element on a new line, I want to overwrite the previous output with the program's newest output.

I am using macosx.

I have tried a few ways:

```
// 'f' is the current element of the array
b := bytes.NewBufferString("")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("\rCould not retrieve file info for %s\n", f)
    b.Reset()
} else {
    fmt.Printf("\rRetrieved %s\n", f)
    b.Reset()
}
```

A second way was to remove `\r` from the string and add and additional Printf before each output: `fmt.Printf("\033[0;0H")`.

Comment: What happens if you remove the '\n' from the end of the string?

Comment: I removed the \n. Oddly enough on some lines the stdout is overwritten but on most it is still not working. 


I also removed the code from the bytes package. It seems it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [ANSI Escape Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

First, save the position of the cursor with `fmt.Print("\033[s")`, then for each line, restore the position and clear the line before printing the line with `fmt.Print("\033[u\033[K")`

Your code could be:

```golang
// before entering the loop
fmt.Print("\033[s") // save the cursor position

for ... {
    ...
    fmt.Print("\033[u\033[K") // restore the cursor position and clear the line
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Could not retrieve file info for %s\n", f)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Retrieved %s\n", f)
    }
    ...
}
```

It should work unless your program prints the line at the bottom of the screen, generating a scrolling of your text. In this case, you should remove the `\n` and make sure that no line exceeds the screen (or window) width.

Another option could be to move the cursor up after each write:

```golang
for ... {
    ...
    fmt.Print("\033[G\033[K") // move the cursor left and clear the line
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Could not retrieve file info for %s\n", f)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Retrieved %s\n", f)
    }
    fmt.Print("\033[A") // move the cursor up
    ...
}
```

Again, this works as long as your line fits on the screen/window width.

Comment: This is not Go syntax, don't share pseudo code mixed with Go language.